# JNIでJava側にC++で作成した可変長配列を返したい

Tags: java, c++, jni

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_xxxx_helloworld_MainActivity_intFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jstring absolutePath) {// 最初の2引数は必須、3つ目から利用したい引数

    int nRet = 0;
    std::vector<double> vInfo;
    vInfo.emplace_back(1.1);
    vInfo.emplace_back(2.2);
    vInfo.emplace_back(3.3);
    vInfo.emplace_back(4.4);

    return nRet;
}
```

std::vectorのvInfo(実際にどれぐらい作られるかは不明)を何らかの方法でjava側に返す方法を知りたいです。
引数や戻り値は仮設定のため変更可能です。

**下記で対応可能でした。**

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_xxxx_helloworld_MainActivity_InfoFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jstring absolutePath) {// 最初の2引数は必須、3つ目から利用したい引数を追加

    std::vector<double> vInfo;
    vInfo.emplace_back(1.1);
    vInfo.emplace_back(2.2);
    vInfo.emplace_back(3.3);
    vInfo.emplace_back(4.4);

    jdouble arrValues[vInfo.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < vInfo.size(); i++){
        arrValues[i] = vInfo[i];
    };

    jdoubleArray dbArray = env->NewDoubleArray(vInfo.size());
    env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(dbArray, 0, vCnfo.size(), arrValues);

    return dbArray;
}
```

Java側

```
public native double[] InfoFromJNI(String absolutePath);

double[] dbInfo = InfoFromJNI(imagePath);
int nLength = dbInfo.length;
// 後処理
```

Comment: Java側として受け取りたい型（コレクション？配列型？）の指定はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 個数が欲しいためArrayList<double>とかで返ってくると嬉しいですが、javaには明るくないためjava側で値と個数がわかる方法であれば大丈夫です。

Comment: 解決したため、本文に追記で対応しました。

Comment: @wtnb さん、お疲れさまでした！　スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨されています。自己回答を承認することもできますので、本文への追記部分を回答として分離して頂けると幸いです。お手数ですがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(_ _)>